# How can I dynamically add/remove elements in an element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Here's my code. I'm trying to make it such that as you change the dropdown box, it will dynamically show more or less QLineEdits for input. This is just the latest iteration of testing

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
    QInputDialog, QApplication, QComboBox, QFrame)

import numpy as np


class GUI(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initgui()

    def initgui(self):
        #
        # Set up GUI 
        #
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
        self.move(300, 300)
        combobox = QComboBox(self)
        for i in range(1, 10, 1):
            combobox.addItem(str(i + 1))
        combobox.activated[str].connect(self.comboboxchanged)
        self.setWindowTitle("Testing Easy Setup")
        self.show()

    def comboboxchanged(self, text):
        frame = QWidget(self)
        frame.hide()
        for num in range(0, int(text), 1):
            QLineEdit(frame).move(60, num * 19)
        frame.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you pass a parent to a widget it is placed in the 0, 0 position with respect to the parent, in your case `QFrame` is on top of `QComboBox` since both are in the 0, 0 position. The proper thing is to use layouts. On the other hand you have to eliminate the widgets before adding new ones for it, we create a function that eliminates those items.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def clearLayout(lay):
    while lay.count() > 0:
        item = lay.takeAt(0)
        widget = item.widget()
        if widget:
            widget.deleteLater()
        del item


class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initgui()

    def initgui(self):
        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        vlay1 = QVBoxLayout()
        combobox = QComboBox(self)
        combobox.addItems([str(i) for i in range(2, 11)])
        vlay1.addWidget(combobox)
        vlay1.addItem(QSpacerItem(20, 245, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))

        self.vlay2 = QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addLayout(vlay1)
        lay.addLayout(self.vlay2)
        self.comboboxchanged(combobox.currentText())
        combobox.activated[str].connect(self.comboboxchanged)
        self.setWindowTitle("Testing Easy Setup")
        self.show()

    def comboboxchanged(self, text):
        clearLayout(self.vlay2)
        for num in range(0, int(text)):
            self.vlay2.addWidget(QLineEdit(self))
        self.vlay2.addItem(QSpacerItem(20, 245, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but the code explained enough of what I needed to get me to the eventual resolution